# Android: Does Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE require vibrate permission?

Tags: java, android, android-notifications, vibration, android-vibration

Sometimes I read that

`notification.defaults|= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;`

and

`notification.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_ALL;`

requires the vibrate permission

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" ></uses-permission>`

But sometimes I read that it doesn't.

Which one is the correct information?

Comment: Yes it does require the vibrate permission. Without the permission the app won't run!

Comment: Yes permission is needed

Comment: Yes You have to specify permission

Comment: Interestingly I could run this (using DEFAULT_ALL) on one device (Nexus 4 running 4.2) without requesting the VIBRATE permission, but it would crash on another (Nexus S running 4.1).

Comment: Same here, HTC ONE X with 4.2 didn't need the permission

Comment: I bet they've changed it in 4.2 then. I can understand why they would change that though. I mean, why would you need permission to do something the user has set as default?

Comment: I experienced a similar funny behaviour: I was showing notifications in the App with `Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE` with no problems on all devices *until* I added permissions for push notifications support. As soon as I added that, I was getting crashes because I did not include the `VIBRATE` permission on devices pre 4.2 (so only 4.0.X - 4.1.X).

Comment: Permissions for push notifications? I'm using push notifications in my app without a permission and it doesn't give me any errors

Comment: I've tested it on my Nexus 4 on lollipop, it do not need this permission.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13602190/java-lang-securityexception-requires-vibrate-permission-on-jelly-bean-4-2

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok, apparently, you do need the vibrate permission. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, see the docs: https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/app/Notification#default_vibrate

Answer (score 7):

You may be interested in reading: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/cc2e849

As of 4.2.1:

> Notification vibration improvements: [DO NOT MERGE]
>
> - When notifications vibrate as a fallback (that is,    because they want to play a sound but the device is in    vibrate mode), this no
>     longer requires the VIBRATE    permission.
> - As a bonus, if your notifications use DEFAULT_VIBRATE,    you don't need the VIBRATE permission either.
> - If you specify a custom vibration pattern, you'll still    need the VIBRATE permission for that.
> - Notifications vibrating in fallback mode use same    vibration pattern but can be changed easily in future.
> - The DEFAULT_VIBRATE and fallback vibrate patterns are now    specified in config.xml.

Comment: much better answer then just answer "yes" (as in accepted answer), but usually we don't need this permission, so the actual answer is "no"

Comment: But isn't the actual answer "it depends on your android version"?