# An error occured while executing doInBackground() when create notification with image from URL

Tags: android, notifications, android-4.2-jelly-bean

i'm trying notification sample  with image from URL. Notification success created , but the application force close with error this

```
03-06 09:31:41.790: E/AndroidRuntime(13432): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    03-06 09:31:41.790: E/AndroidRuntime(13432): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
    03-06 09:31:41.790: E/AndroidRuntime(13432):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
    03-06 09:31:41.790: E/AndroidRuntime(13432):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
    03-06 09:31:41.790: E/AndroidRuntime(13432):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
    03-06 09:31:41.790: E/AndroidRuntime(13432):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
    03-06 09:31:41.790: E/AndroidRuntime(13432):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
    03-06 09:31:41.790: E/AndroidRuntime(13432):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
    03-06 09:31:41.790: E/AndroidRuntime(13432):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
    03-06 09:31:41.790: E/AndroidRuntime(13432):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
    03-06 09:31:41.790: E/AndroidRuntime(13432):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
    03-06 09:31:41.790: E/AndroidRuntime(13432): Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Requires VIBRATE permission
    03-06 09:31:41.790: E/AndroidRuntime(13432):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1425)
    03-06 09:31:41.790: E/AndroidRuntime(13432):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1379)
    03-06 09:31:41.790: E/AndroidRuntime(13432):    at android.app.INotificationManager$Stub$Proxy.enqueueNotificationWithTag(INotificationManager.java:302)
    03-06 09:31:41.790: E/AndroidRuntime(13432):    at android.app.NotificationManager.notify(NotificationManager.java:124)
    03-06 09:31:41.790: E/AndroidRuntime(13432):    at android.app.NotificationManager.notify(NotificationManager.java:103)
    03-06 09:31:41.790: E/AndroidRuntime(13432):    at com.codeversed.example.Notifications.MainActivity$CreateNotification.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:121)
    03-06 09:31:41.790: E/AndroidRuntime(13432):    at com.codeversed.example.Notifications.MainActivity$CreateNotification.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
    03-06 09:31:41.790: E/AndroidRuntime(13432):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
    03-06 09:31:41.790: E/AndroidRuntime(13432):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
    03-06 09:31:41.790: E/AndroidRuntime(13432):    ... 5 more
```

and this part of my code notification

```
private Notification setBigTextStyleNotification() {
        Bitmap remote_picture = null;

        // Create the style object with BigTextStyle subclass.
        NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle notiStyle = new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle();
        notiStyle.setBigContentTitle("Big Text Expanded");
        notiStyle.setSummaryText("Nice big text.");

        remote_picture = getBitmapFromURL(sample_url);

        // Add the big text to the style.
        CharSequence bigText = "This is an example of a large string to demo how much " +
                               "text you can show in a 'Big Text Style' notification.";
        notiStyle.bigText(bigText);

        // Creates an explicit intent for an ResultActivity to receive.
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, ResultActivity.class);

        // This ensures that the back button follows the recommended convention for the back key.
        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);

        // Adds the back stack for the Intent (but not the Intent itself).
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(ResultActivity.class);

        // Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack.
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        return new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setLargeIcon(remote_picture)
                .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
                .addAction(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "One", resultPendingIntent)
                .addAction(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Two", resultPendingIntent)
                .addAction(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Three", resultPendingIntent)
                .setContentTitle("Big Text Normal")
                .setContentText("This is an example of a Big Text Style.")
                .setStyle(notiStyle).build();
    }

    public Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String strURL) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(strURL);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            return myBitmap;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

**remote_picture = getBitmapFromURL(sample_url)** is to get image from url . how to fix it ? thanks very much and sorry for my english.

Comment: as in log `03-06 09:31:41.790: E/AndroidRuntime(13432): Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Requires VIBRATE permission` . have you added VIBRATE permission in AndroidManifest ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is you issue:

```
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Requires VIBRATE permission
```

You need to add this permission to your android manifest to resolve it

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

Comment: FYI, this is not the OP's code the problem here, he is not using the notification vibration. This is a bug in Android, we should not be forced to add this permission but we have to because it is still bugged on 4.2 and 4.3. You can check this other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13602190/java-lang-securityexception-requires-vibrate-permission-on-jelly-bean-4-2