# Requires VIBRATE permission Exception although Permission is in Manifest

Tags: java, android, android-manifest, android-vibration

I am developing an App for a smartwatch using Android 6.01 API 23. 
I want to add some vibration capabilities.
I have defined in my `AndroidManifest.xml` the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="myexample.warehousehelper.mobile">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

I am getting the following exception

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{myexample.warehousehelper/myexample.warehousehelper.wear.MainActivity}: 
java.lang.SecurityException: Requires VIBRATE permission
```

The "vibration call" is as follows:

```
Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
v.vibrate(200);
```

Any hint why is this behaviour?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13602190/java-lang-securityexception-requires-vibrate-permission-on-jelly-bean-4-2

Comment: android marshmallow version require runtime permission not install time

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33162152/storage-permission-error-in-marshmallow/33163206#33163206

Comment: just add there `android.Manifest.permission.VIBRATE`  instead of `android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it is extremely painful to admit that i've posted the wrong Manifest. I've granted the permission to the `mobile` version and not to the `wear` version. That is, I used the wrong `Manifest.xml`.

Now it is working properly without doing anything but the permissions.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: We all make these kinds of mistakes.  That's in part why stackoverflow exists!